# Testing express routes using curl

Tags: curl, express, mongoose, mean-stack

This is the route in express

```
  router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res) {
      res.json(req.post);
    });

router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

How to hit this routes using curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find answer [here](https://gist.github.com/iksose/9401758).

```
`router.get('/posts/:post`'
```

can be tested using

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:3000/posts/55d315796083c16c3bac93d8
```

Similarly the curl for

```
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote'
```

is

```
curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/55d315796083c16c3bac93d8/upvote
```